# Which offensive spell causes the highest damage?

Tags: two-worlds-2

I would like to know, with 2 worlds 2's new magic system, which is the best (highest damage) offensive spell?

If anyone has any other spell ideas please add an answer below!

Comment: haven't played the 2nd one yet, but knowing the first one, its probably.... summon wolf :P

Comment: @yx01 The spells are entirely different from two worlds 1, so no, i don't think that's it.

Comment: that was meant to be a joke, sorry :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made this and it works like a charm:

> Section 1: fire (effect) + missile
>   (carrier) + damage (modifier) + spray
>   [w](modifier, the more the better) +
>   ricochet (modifier, the more the
>   better)
>
> Section 2: air (effect) + enchant
>   (carrier) + damage (modifier) + time
>   (modifier)

As a result, you obtain the following: after firing the missile, it spray into W missiles (depending on how many cards you used), when it hits the target it deals X fire damage to the enemy who’s hit, in addition, after each hit it spawns a shower of anvils with Y area damage for a specific time. Bounced missiles hit another Z enemies (depending on how many cards you used), which also sustains X and Y damage

As i said the damage depends on the number of cards used, but this is the highest damage i can make so far

Answer (score -1):

Don't really know, but fire makes the most in-game damage (ironically it does in real life too). Grab the best fire spells, and the most you can get fill them in, then destroy the missile by adding 10+ missiles (you can do that for the fire card too) then murder the damage and the spray modifier. You can add whatever you want to this spell, I've maxed out everything in magic just in case.

To sum it up: add as many spellcards as possible, max out fire. Fire makes the most damage. Make sure it's spray. Good luck, man.